# How to make puppeteer load websites faster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, automation, puppeteer

so am working  with puppeteer to automate stuffs and it working fine, but when i load the website it take a bit more time to load than my normal website, i tried doing cache using this

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
let time = new Date()
async function test() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true, 
       executablePath:"D:\\Desktop\\node_modules\\puppeteer\\.local-chromium\\win64-848005\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe",
        args: ['--no-sandbox'], 
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const response = await page.goto('https://example.com/');
    console.log(`${new Date() -time }`)
    console.log(response);
    await browser.close();
}
```

and it worked for the example.com the cache was stored  and it became faster to load but my targeted website seem to dont allow for cache storing

[image]

any another way to fasten the process ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want the site to load faster when scraping and you do not rely on some of the images or javascript, you have the possibility to block these resources.

**Blocking by Resource Type**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', (req) => {
    if (req.resourceType() === 'image') {
      req.abort();
    } else {
      req.continue();
    }
  });

  await page.goto('https://bbc.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'no-images.png', fullPage: true});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

**Blocking by Domain**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const options = {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    timeout: 30000,
  };

  // Before: Normal navigtation
  await page.goto('https://theverge.com', options);
  await page.screenshot({path: 'before.png', fullPage: true});
  const metrics = await page.metrics();
  console.info(metrics);

  // After: Navigation with some domains blocked

  // Array of third-party domains to block
  const blockedDomains = [
    'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com',
    'https://creativecdn.com',
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com',
    'https://cdn.krxd.net',
    'https://adservice.google.com',
    'https://cdn.concert.io',
    'https://z.moatads.com',
    'https://cdn.permutive.com'];
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (request) => {
    const url = request.url();
    if (blockedDomains.some((d) => url.startsWith(d))) {
      request.abort();
    } else {
      request.continue();
    }
  });

  await page.goto('https://theverge.com', options);
  await page.screenshot({path: 'after.png', fullPage: true});

  const metricsAfter = await page.metrics();
  console.info(metricsAfter);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Source:
https://github.com/addyosmani/puppeteer-webperf

Comment: Thank you for you answer but i already did this and sometimes the website dont have third-party domains to block as well as sometimes blocking images/css may get you detected by the antibot , Thank you again.